# /bin/dash: strange behavior when matching wildcard *

Tags: sh

I want to iterate over all files in given directory. This is my script (simplified):

```
#!/bin/sh

for F in /tmp/ZZZ/* ; do
    echo $F
done
```

This works as expected, when directory `/tmp/ZZZ/` contains files:

```
$ ./myscript.sh      
/tmp/ZZZ/aaa
```

But the problem is, when directory is empty, instead of not echoing anything, the script echos the literal `*`:

```
$ ./myscript.sh      
/tmp/ZZZ/*
```

**Why is this happening?**

**Is there any way change this behavior of the shell ?**

Comment: I don't know about dash, but this is the expected behavior for bash, at least. You might want to check whether dash has the same [nullglob option](http://bash.cumulonim.biz/NullGlob.html) that bash does.

Comment: @oguz ismail - so how can I solve the problem ?

Comment: @oguz ismail - I don't need a portable way. I just need it to work on linux.

Comment: You could check that an item with the given pathname exists before `echo`ing the name. To do that, instead of just `echo "$F"` use `[ -e "$F" ] && echo "$F"`